# Error trying to install libjpeg-devel with elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, libjpeg, python-imaging-library

I am trying to do some image resizing on my Django application running on AWS Elastic beanstalk, so I am trying to install Pillow to do the job.

As described in some previous posts, I am adding

```
packages:
  yum:
    libjpeg-devel: '6b'
```

at the top of my *.ebextension/myapp.config*

My *requirement.txt* includes:

```
Django==1.6.7
boto>=2.32.1
django-filter>=0.7
django-password-reset>=0.7
django-storages>=1.1.8
django-taggit==0.12
djangorestframework>=2.3.13
django-bootstrap3>=4.11.0
django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker>=2.2.3
python-dateutil>=2.2
pytz>=2014.2
six>=1.7.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
yolk==0.4.3
Pillow==2.5.3
googlemaps==1.0.2
MySQL-python>=1.2.5
```

But when I either `eb start` or `git aws.push`, I get the following error in my elastic beanstalk log:

```
2014-09-15 07:10:23,596 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2014-09-15 07:10:23,598 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_ampervue
2014-09-15 07:10:32,556 [ERROR] libjpeg-devel-6b is not available to be installed
2014-09-15 07:10:32,557 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_ampervue: Yum    does not have libjpeg-devel-6b available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 511, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 216, in build
changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages, self._auth_config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 74, in apply
    raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
ToolError: Yum does not have libjpeg-devel-6b available for installation
2014-09-15 07:10:32,560 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Yum does not have libjpeg-devel-6b available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 122, in <module>
    worklog.build(detail.metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 117, in build
Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 502, in build
self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 511, in run_config
CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 216, in build
changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages, self._auth_config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 74, in apply
raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
ToolError: Yum does not have libjpeg-devel-6b available for installation
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to get it to install by using the `libjpeg-turbo-devel` package without the specific version. The YAML is below:

```
packages:
    yum:
        libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
```

If you specifically need that version, you might want to investigate the `libjpeg-turbo` equivalent.

One way to manually figure these things out is to either SSH into an actual instance that is in your environment or launch a new one.

In this case, to test this, when I SSH'd in and ran the yum install, this happened:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ sudo yum install libjpeg-devel
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.1-3.4.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

As you can see, it resolves to `libjpeg-turbo-devel` instead.

Comment: I had to terminate and re-start the instance but this worked well. Many thanks!